# Microsoft USD - Save parameters inside $Settings from C# Code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

I want to save different parameters inside **$Settings** , since it is global and i want to use these values even when the session is transferred that is when it becomes null.

I am currently doing this,

```
var updatedContext = new Context(ctx)
{
[ContextParameterName] = ContextVals
}; 
FireChangeContext(new ContextEventArgs(updatedContext));
```

But through this i am only able to save values inside $Context.  I want the values to be stored inside **$Settings**.

Looking forward to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through **FireRequestAction**

```
FireRequestAction(new RequestActionEventArgs(<<HostedControl>>, <<ActionName>>, <<Your Data>>);
```

Hosted Control will be **Global Manager**, Action will be **SaveSetting** and with that Data you want to store inside Settings.